# Why is the / proc / kcore file so large?

Tags: linux

Why is the / proc / kcore file so large? 128T, and when the disk snapshot is taken, the capacity of the snapshot is not the right size.

Comment: `/proc` is the mount point of `procfs`, which is a virtual file system. Nothing you see there is actually taking up any disc space

Comment: I know it doesn't take up disk space, but why is the snapshot size incorrect when using Google cloud's disk snapshot feature? I only used 20G/200G, but the snapshot size is 178G, which should be the space occupied by the kcroe files.

Answer (score 0):

This may have something to do with how files are deleted in linux. When you delete a file in linux, the data isn't really deleted. Instead, the file system essentially marks the associated *inode* and the *blocks* where the data was stored, as unused.

This is done to avoid the overhead of actually *zeroing* (i.e. writing the blocks with 0s), and is also the reason why you can recover deleted files.

What's probably happening is the snapshot is also accounting for memory blocks that were *marked* as unused/deleted. The files you see inside `/proc/` aren't real files and will not affect your disc usage.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't take up disk space, but I used the kill command to clean up the process of taking up files that have been deleted, but it still doesn't work, and the disk snapshot is still large

Comment: Killing any processes will not affect your disc usage. The only way to clear up the space is to do a deep format of the disc/partition